# MongoDB NodeJS Driver: Duplicate key `E11000` extract index name

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling

While using MongoDB NodeJS driver (or even mongoose), when inserting a new document, an `E11000` error may return indicating a duplicate key collision has occurred.

What if the collection I am inserting into has multiple unique indices and I want to identify which one of them is hit (e.g. to notify the user the user that his username and/or email is already taken)?

This is the error raised after inserting a document with a colliding index:

```
{
    "name": "MongoError",
    "message": "E11000 duplicate key error index: db.users.$_id_ dup key: { : \"blucell\" }",
    "driver": true,
    "index": 0,
    "code": 11000,
    "errmsg": "E11000 duplicate key error index: db.users.$_id_ dup key: { : \"blucell\" }"
}
```

The only notion of the index causing the problem is in the message, which changes over time (already differs between mongo 2.x and 3.x).

Is there any more future-proof/easier way of checking which element/index is causing the collision?

Comment: Why can't you just query, e.g. db.users.find({_id:"blucell"}), before trying to insert the document?  You can do this for all unique indexed fields, not just _id.  If there are matches, you'll know not to insert the document and can inform that the username or email is already in use.

Comment: Yes, this works, but it is a lot of overhead, and then you have to take care of possible data races which will not lead to a so-much-clean code. I hope there is a more native solution out there

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no method as of MongoDB 3.4.7 that lists the colliding indexes in a separate, easy to parse field.

There is a discussion in Mongoose regarding this, but the solutions all rely on parsing the actual error message (see https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2129).

Since the node driver just reports back the error given by the server, there is a MongoDB feature request for exactly this functionality (see [SERVER-4637](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4637)). I would suggest commenting/upvoting on the feature request to raise awareness of the issue.